# Editing Files in My account Magento CE

Tags: magento-1.7

Hello I am using Magento CE 1.7.2 I am trying to edit the customers "My Account" Pages
I cannot find what file to edit to change the layout and design of the following:
My account:
    Account Dash Board (got this to work editing customer/account/dashboard.phtml)
    Account Information (Tried customer/account/dashboard/info.phtml Didn't work)
    Address Book (Tried customer/account/dashboard/address.phtml Didn't Work)
    My Orders (No idea)
    Newsletter Subscriptions (Tried customer/account/dashboard/newsletter.phtml Didn't Work)

What files do I edit? Please show the directory.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Telling you the exact path would be like *"giving you a fish"*.
Instead, I will *"teach you how to fish"*.

Login to your admin panel in Magento.
Head to *System > Configuration*. At the bottom of your left menu you will find a *Developper* link.
Head to this link, then in the upper left of the given page, select a webiste in the dropbox under *Current Configuration Scope*.

Open the *Debug* section and set *Template Path Hints* to *Yes*.
Reload your customer page in frontend. Tada! You can now see where is every single files you have to edit to change anything in your Magento.